# How to get the name of a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variable-names, delegated-properties

I have a Kotlin class in my application with a lot of attributes, what I want to build is a method that stores the variable name in a dictionary. The dictionary looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, Pair<Any, Any>>()
```

The purpose of this is to store the changes made to a certain attribute, I store the name of the variable as the key and in the Pair I store the old value and the new value. To notify a change I use the Observer pattern. So whenever a setter is called from an attribute a change will be notified and stored to the dictionary.

The code below results in the folowing:

```
var person = Person("Harry", 44)
person.age = 45
```

`HashMap("age", (44, 45))`

Right now I am just hardcoding the variable name in as a String, so my question is:

**How to dynamicly get the name of a variable in Kotlin?**

I saw the same question in Java: [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Also some other questions about the same topic claiming it is not possible: [Get the name property of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674153/get-the-name-property-of-a-variable)

I can understand that it is not possible to get the name of a variable, because the compiler simple doesn't have that information, but I am still currious to see if others have any sollution for this problem.

Comment: do you know already what [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) are?

Comment: No I was not aware of delegated properties, looks nice I will take a look at that, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think delegate properties is the solution to my problem:

```
class Delegate {
operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
    return "$thisRef, thank you for delegating '${property.name}' to me!"
}

operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
    println("$value has been assigned to '${property.name}' in $thisRef.")
  }
}
```

Credits go to: [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6202869/roland)
Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html

Comment: well... maybe it suffices your needs, but be sure to also look at the [observable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#observable) and [properties in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) variants, which might even be more appropriate or easier to implement.

Answer (score 43):

As stated in the Kotlin [documentation about Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html):

```
val x = 1

fun main() {
    println(::x.get())
    println(::x.name) 
}
```

The expression `::x` evaluates to a property object of type `KProperty<Int>`, which allows us to read its value using `get()` or retrieve the property name using the `name` property.

Comment: How to do this with `this`?

Answer (score 9):

Use `memberProperties` to get the names of the class attributes and others properties. For instance:

```
YourClass::class.memberProperties.map {
 println(it.name)
 println(it.returnType)
}
```

Comment: How can i get the value of the field as well ?